# Stop a function to start another function in Tkinter

Tags: python, function, loops, tkinter, call

so I want to make a questionnaire/survey chatbot. Here's my GUI python code so far.

```
# GUI
root = Tk()
root.title("Chatbot")

BG_GRAY = "#ABB2B9"
BG_COLOR = "#17202A"
TEXT_COLOR = "#EAECEE"

FONT = "Helvetica 14"
FONT_BOLD = "Helvetica 13 bold"
# Send function
def send():
    send1 = "Anda:\n " + e.get() + "\n"
    user = e.get()
    txt.insert(END, "\n" + send1)
    txt.see('end')
    try:
        if int(user) not in [1,2]:
            txt.insert(END,"\n"+"Chatbot:\nTolong tuliskan angka dengan benar\n")
            txt.see('end')
        else:
            if int(user)==2:
                txt.insert(END,"\n"+"Chatbot:\n")
                txt.see('end')
            else:
                predfunc()
                root.after(0,predfunc)
    except ValueError:
        txt.insert(END,"\n"+"Chatbot:\nTolong tuliskan angka dengan benar\n")
        txt.see('end')
    e.delete(0, END)

def predfunc():
    count=0
    userdata=[]
    questions=["Chatbot:\n",
    "Chatbot:\n",
    "Chatbot:\n",
    "Chatbot:\n",
    "Chatbot:\n",
    "Chatbot:\n",
    "Chatbot:\n",
    "Chatbot:\n",
    "Chatbot:\n",
    "Chatbot:\n",
    "Chatbot:\n"
    ]
    e.delete(0,END)
    txt.insert(END, "\n", questions[count] + "\n")
    txt.see('end')
    ans = e.get()
    sendans = "Anda:\n " + e.get() + "\n"
    txt.insert(END, "\n" + sendans)
    txt.see('end')
    userdata.append(ans)
    count+=1
    if count >= len(questions):
        root.after(10,predfunc)
    else:
        pass
    e.delete(0, END)

lable1 = Label(root, bg=BG_COLOR, fg=TEXT_COLOR, text="Welcome", font=FONT_BOLD, pady=10, width=20, height=1).grid(
    row=0)

txt = Text(root, bg=BG_COLOR, fg=TEXT_COLOR, font=FONT, width=60)
txt.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
txt.insert(END,"\n"+"Chatbot:\nHalo, saya ChatBot")
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root,command=txt.yview)
scrollbar.place(relheight=1, relx=1, rely=0, anchor='ne')

e = Entry(root, bg="#2C3E50", fg=TEXT_COLOR, font=FONT, width=55)
e.grid(row=2, column=0)


sendb = Button(root, text="Send", font=FONT_BOLD, bg=BG_GRAY,
            command=send)
sendb.grid(row=2, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

As you can see in the send function, I want to start the predfunc function and stop the send function whenever user input equals 1. How can I do that? as I've tried everything and none worked. The predfunc doesn't start when the input equals 1. I want to stop the send function loop because the user inputs will be different everytime and the validation in the start of send function isn't designed for every inputs. Sorry if that wasn't unclear, English is my second language. Please help me. I already have the python logic but the GUI is so much harder.

Comment: Why do you think that `predfunc()` is not executed when the input is 1? I added `print('predfunc')` at the beginning of `predfunc()` and I got two `predfunc` in the console when the input is 1.

Comment: using `predfunc()` and next `root.after(0,predfunc)` you runs the same function twice. Use only one of this lines.

Comment: `else: pass` is useless. You can use `if` without `else`

Comment: everytime when you run `predfunct()` (even using `after()`) it set again local `count = 0` - you would have to keep it in global variable or you should send value as parameter `def predfunct(count):` and `after(10, predfunct, count)`. The same problem is with `userdata` - every execution set new local `userdata = []`